# .NET MVC oData Bind Navigation property to 2 entity sets

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, odata

I am pretty new to .NET MVC and trying to create an oData web service for the first time.  I have 3 tables that are referenced using Entity Framework: Groups, SubGroups, Links.

I used the out of the box Visual Studio oData EF creation for the 3 tables and the Groups web service appears to be working fine.  However the SubGroups table displays the following error:

```
Cannot automatically bind the navigation property 'SubGroups' on entity type 'Quick_Links.Models.Group' for the source entity set 'Groups' because there are two or more matching target entity sets.
```

My models have not been changed from what was generated by VS and they look like the following:

GROUP:

```
namespace Quick_Links.Models
{
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Data.Entity.Spatial;

public partial class Group
{
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public Group()
    {
        SubGroups = new HashSet<SubGroup>();
    }

    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public int GroupID { get; set; }

    public bool? GroupActive { get; set; }

    [StringLength(50)]
    public string GroupName { get; set; }

    [StringLength(50)]
    public string GroupSecurity { get; set; }

    [StringLength(50)]
    public string GroupAdmin { get; set; }

    [StringLength(50)]
    public string UpdateByEID { get; set; }

    public DateTime? UpdateDatetime { get; set; }

    [StringLength(50)]
    public string CreateByEID { get; set; }

    public DateTime? CreateDatetime { get; set; }

    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<SubGroup> SubGroups { get; set; }
}
}
```

SUBGROUP:

```
namespace Quick_Links.Models
{
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Data.Entity.Spatial;

public partial class SubGroup
{
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public SubGroup()
    {
        Links = new HashSet<Link>();
    }

    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public int SubGroupID { get; set; }

    public bool? SubGroupActive { get; set; }

    public int? GroupID { get; set; }

    [StringLength(50)]
    public string SubGroupName { get; set; }

    public int? SubGroupOrder { get; set; }

    [StringLength(50)]
    public string SubGroupSecurity { get; set; }

    [StringLength(50)]
    public string UpdateByEID { get; set; }

    public DateTime? UpdateDatetime { get; set; }

    [StringLength(50)]
    public string CreateByEID { get; set; }

    public DateTime? CreateDatetime { get; set; }

    public virtual Group Group { get; set; }

    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<Link> Links { get; set; }
}
}
```

I can post the Links model if needed but I am thinking it is the same problem as Groups/SubGroups.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

EDIT: Here is my dataset:

```
namespace Quick_Links.Models
{
using System;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Linq;

public partial class QuickLinks : DbContext
{
    public QuickLinks()
        : base("name=QuickLinks")
    {
    }

    public virtual DbSet<Group> Groups { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Link> Links { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<SubGroup> SubGroups { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Group>()
            .Property(e => e.GroupName)
            .IsUnicode(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Group>()
            .Property(e => e.GroupSecurity)
            .IsUnicode(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Group>()
            .Property(e => e.GroupAdmin)
            .IsUnicode(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Group>()
            .Property(e => e.UpdateByEID)
            .IsUnicode(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Group>()
            .Property(e => e.CreateByEID)
            .IsUnicode(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Link>()
            .Property(e => e.LinkName)
            .IsUnicode(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Link>()
            .Property(e => e.LinkURL)
            .IsUnicode(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Link>()
            .Property(e => e.LinkSecurity)
            .IsUnicode(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Link>()
            .Property(e => e.UpdateByEID)
            .IsUnicode(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Link>()
            .Property(e => e.CreateByEID)
            .IsUnicode(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<SubGroup>()
            .Property(e => e.SubGroupName)
            .IsUnicode(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<SubGroup>()
            .Property(e => e.SubGroupSecurity)
            .IsUnicode(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<SubGroup>()
            .Property(e => e.UpdateByEID)
            .IsUnicode(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<SubGroup>()
            .Property(e => e.CreateByEID)
            .IsUnicode(false);
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This was a mistake with referencing the wrong entity set in my WebAPIConfig.  I updated it to the following to fix the problem:

```
builder.EntitySet<Group>("Groups");
        builder.EntitySet<SubGroup>("SubGroups");
        builder.EntitySet<Link>("Links");
```